# Como alterar o Namespace de um projeto C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

O projeto foi criado com o nome Windows e quero alterar. O problema é que se eu simplesmente clicar com o botão direito no projeto e renomear, o projeto fica cheio de erro. 
Tentei mudar o Assembly name  e o Default namespace mas também ocasiona um monte de erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual a maneira correta de renomear? se possível.

Comment: Se você mudou o nome do projeto, não mudou o `namespace`. Qual você quer mudar de fato? Dê mais detalhes de como está o projeto, poste uma *screenshot*  dele, algum trecho de código que seja relevante, ponde está dando erro.

Comment: Coloquei um print dos lugares que quero alterar. Se eu mudar nesses lugares, da erro no projeto em geral, ele não compila.

Comment: Dê exemplos de erros apresentados.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eu faço da seguinte forma:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>;
- Expressão de busca (Find what): "using Windows;", ou então "namespace Windows"
- Substituir por (Replace with): "using NovoNomeDeNamespace;" (atenção para manter os sinais de ponto-e-vírgula ao final), ou então "namespace NovoNomeDeNamespace";
- Localizar em (Look in): Solução inteira (Entire Solution).

Algumas ferramentas fazem isso por você, como o ReSharper, mas ele não é gratuito, então essa seria a maneira sem custos.

---

### Sobre *Assembly Name* e *Default Workspace*:

O raciocínio é o mesmo. Primeiro mude os nomes nas propriedades, depois execute o procedimento descrito acima, porque a renomeação dos *namespaces* não é automática.

Comment: Cigano, muito obrigado. Tenho o ReSharper e vou tentar alterar por ele.

Comment: @Cigano Morrison Mendez, qual a diferença entre estes assembly name, default workspace e namespace? Todos devem conter sempre o mesmo nome?

Comment: @DanOver Assembly Name é o nome que a DLL terá. Default Namespace é o Namespace raiz do projeto. Não sei o que é Default Workspace. Não, nem sempre todos devem conter o mesmo nome. Depende do que você precisa fazer.